# Reducing Tor service shutdown time

Tags: configuration, server, server-administration

Can I somehow reduce the time it takes Tor to shutdown? In my log I see

```
Interrupt: we have stopped accepting new connections, and will shut down in 30 seconds. Interrupt again to exit now.
```

Since I am running it as service I could send it a signal to stop, but I would prefer a configuration-wise solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer "you can't", the description is: after sending a termination signal - it's wise to let the network find another chains, so that's why there's a delay in order, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with it. To reduce the delay - it does **not** works all the times - you can set via ControlPort "DisableNetwork 1" and give Tor 5-10 seconds, then you'll shut it down. But it does not works faster all the times, so - as my advise - just let it finish itself in a regular way, there's no hurry.

UPDATE:

But as a side note - you should script the 2nd interrupt shutdown for emergency shutdown cases, like your UPS battery is almost gone: the faster the shutdown is in that cases - the better, because it will prevent the filesystem corruption. Usual shutdown timings for tor are about 10-15 seconds as for me, so - thats' the strategy I'm proposing for your "fast shutdown case":

- **If you're using SystemD** - then you have nothing to worry about, as I've switched on it on some of my VMs, it's not a problem at all in case of Debian stretch - VM shuts itself down in 2-5 seconds more time than just a blank one.
- **If you're using daemontools and/or init.d scripts** - just send a "DisableNetwork 1" *a 2-3 seconds before* sending the shutdown machine-wide via `shutdown` command, that's how it working in my old-style setups I was talking about in original answer. a good workaround here can be the next trick: rename the original shutdown-commands binaries to something like `shutdown.orig`, make your own scripts with the original command names - and in that scripts before calling "the orig's" do the telnetting "disablenetwork 1" and sleep for 3 seconds. That's exactly how I'm doing it. So all of your previous machine management scripts will be working as usual, no need to patch every of them - just put scripts at the exact place of the old binaries.

That's it!

Comment: I run Tor in a VM and the long VM shutdown time is annoying. It does not happen often that I have to restart the host system, so my best bet is to script another interrupt at shutdown for those occasions it seems.

Comment: Well, usually rebooting Tor VM even without the disable network, I rarely get the shutdown time greater than 20 seconds.

Comment: @Spikolynn added the details about an emergency shutdown and how exactly I'm doing the shutdown

Comment: You **can**. Setting `ShutdownWaitLength` to a smaller value such as 20 seconds is completely reasonable and will not disrupt the network.

Comment: @nobody yes, it's **physically** tweakable  - even in source - but **no** it is not a good practice. The "wait length" is not a must-limit, it is a "hard limit", and - if you'll take a deeper look at the keepalives e.t.c. timeouts *default values* - it's EXACTLY 30 seconds. As soon as your node will close all the links - it will collapse to shutdown, so this particular timing - IMHO - is not the one messed with

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin it is far too ideal to work out - 30 seconds is only a value that makes most, not all OPs have a chance to build new circuits that could replace the one it is currently using. To make all OPs have this would require 60 seconds, and therefore setting it to 20 seconds does not hurt so much - assuming the time clients start building circuit is uniformly distributed.

Comment: @nobody well, the statement is still the same. of course - if your UPS is running out of battery and it is THAT urgent - yes, it's right to shutdown immediately. but in other cases - give it a 30 seconds... it's defintely NOT THAT much

Answer (score 0):

There is a graceful way to do this. Putting `ShutdownWaitLength 1` in your `torrc` just works.

Comment: a kind of a bad prctice - see my comment